# Is there a way to disable coc-pyright type annotations in vim?

Tags: python-3.x, vim, ubuntu-20.04, vim-plugin, pyright

I use **Vim 9.0.105** and **python3.9.5** and I'm on WSL2 with **Ubuntu20.04**

Like I say in the Title, I have an issue with [coc-pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) which when I write variables
coc-pyright automatically "write" the type annotation.
[Here is a little example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARk9R.png)

The problem is that the annotations are not really written, they are just displayed, so there is a gap between the cursor and what I write when I want to modify or something.

Is there a way to disable the completions of annotations ? Because I haven't find any.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English. If I haven't explained something well, don't hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `:CocConfig`, set `pyright.inlayHints.enable: false`

Comment: Tank you very much. How did you find it? If you can send me the link that would be great.

Comment: Oh I just read the Github repo. It's in the README. But it's all the way towards the end

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I have found it.